# Bitlocker encrypted disk filling too fast

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, encryption, bitlocker

I am in the process of switching from an old hard drive to an SSD.  I decided to take advantage of bitlocker on Windows 10 and have encrypted the new SSD. Now, when I move a folder or file to the new SSD, it appears to take up too much space.

For example:  Folder on old drive is 3 GB.  I move it to new drive and it still shows 3 GB, however the available space on SSD drops from 195 GB to 189 GB.  Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Comment: An encrypted file does not consume more space then an unencrypted file.